# How i can get equal intervals of numeric vector in R?

Tags: r

Can u help me pls with write a function that takes as input a numeric vector x and the number of partitions of the interval k (by default, equal to the number of elements of the vector divided by 10) and does the following:
-finds the minimum and maximum values ​​of the vector elements xmin and xmax (it's easy)
-divides the resulting segment [xmin; xmax] into k equal intervals and counts the number of vector elements belonging to each interval (actual problem)

- Next, a graph should be built, where the abscissa is the middle of the intervals, the ordinate is the number of vector elements belonging to the interval, divided by the total number of points (i think no problem)

i finding function cut() in R, but i don't understand, how i can get intervals from Levels for next steps, and how i can avoid changing numbers around the edges. Look at this for example:

```
#i wrote this part

fun <- function(x, k = (length(x)/10))
{
  xmin <- min(x)
  xmax <- max(x)
  my_cut <- cut((xmin:xmax), breaks=k)
  return(my_cut)
}
```

if try this code, i have:

```
> fun((1:10), 2)
 [1] (0.991,5.5] (0.991,5.5] (0.991,5.5] (0.991,5.5] (0.991,5.5] (5.5,10]    (5.5,10]    (5.5,10]    (5.5,10]    (5.5,10]   
Levels: (0.991,5.5] (5.5,10]
```

as u see, i have 0.991 instead of 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is when setting the number of desired breaks in `cut` the limits are expanded. From the docs:

> When breaks is specified as a single number, the range of the data is divided into breaks pieces of equal length, and then **the outer limits are moved away by 0.1% of the range** to ensure that the extreme values both fall within the break intervals.

Haven't found an option to set this behavior to FALSE. But a workaround or option would be to manually compute and set the breaks via e.g. `seq`. And to compute the counts per interval you could e.g. use `table`.

```r
fun <- function(x, k = length(x) / 10, include.lowest = TRUE, ...) {
  xmin <- min(x)
  xmax <- max(x)
  breaks = seq(xmin, xmax, length.out = k + 1)
  cut(xmin:xmax, breaks = breaks, include.lowest = include.lowest, ...)
}
fun(1:10, 2)
#>  [1] [1,5.5]  [1,5.5]  [1,5.5]  [1,5.5]  [1,5.5]  (5.5,10] (5.5,10] (5.5,10]
#>  [9] (5.5,10] (5.5,10]
#> Levels: [1,5.5] (5.5,10]

table(fun(1:10, 2))
#> 
#>  [1,5.5] (5.5,10] 
#>        5        5
```

Comment: thx! i saw documentation, but have no idea what to do)